# KerasClassifier TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given) on cross_val_score

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn

**I try to cross_val_score on my model and I get the following error:**

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dinhnha1402/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py", line 210, in fit
    return super(KerasClassifier, self).fit(x, y, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dinhnha1402/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/wrappers/scikit_learn.py", line 139, in fit
    **self.filter_sk_params(self.build_fn.__call__))
TypeError: __call__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

This is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(int(128), input_shape=(timesteps, int(128)),return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu', input_shape=(128,),kernel_initializer=initializers.glorot_uniform(seed=0)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(20, activation='softmax'))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax')) 

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

### fit model

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs= epochs, verbose=1, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test))

####Applying K-fold cross validation
classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn=binary_classify_lstm_fc_model(), batch_size=10, epochs=100, verbose=0)
accuracies = cross_val_score(estimator= classifier, X = X_train, y = Y_train, cv=10, scoring="accuracy")#n_jobs= -1
print(accuracies)
```

I cannot find this error anywhere (on google). Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

just drop the "()"

like that:

classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn=binary_classify_lstm_fc_model(), batch_size=10, epochs=100, verbose=0)

=====>

classifier = KerasClassifier(build_fn=binary_classify_lstm_fc_model, batch_size=10, epochs=100, verbose=0)

Answer (score 0):

Just change loss from categorical_crossentropy to mean_squared_error.